# Data Should be Filter with the starting Letter

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to Filter the data by using Starting Letter, But here the data is getting filter with starting and Middle of the letters also.
for example:
Karnataka is the word I need to filter, But If I search with middle letters like "rna" it gets filter,
but in my case I need to get filter by starting letter "K" only..

```
<div class="container">
  <input type ="text" [(ngModel)] ="param"/>  
 </div>

set param(names){
   this.value =names ? this.gettingDatafromServer.filter(item =>item.address.toLowerCase().indexOf(names.toLowerCase())!==-1) : this.gettingDatafromServer
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `.indexOf()` will search the entire string, not just the start. You can instead use the [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method for your `filter()` callback:

```
item => item.address.toLowerCase().startsWith(names.toLowerCase())
```

If you need better browser support, you can [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill) it.